# C++ memory leak object return by function

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

Are there any memory leak? 
Does the object will be delete automaticly?

```
int main ()
{
    SomeClass *someObj;
    ...
    someObj = &foo();
    ...
    return 0;
}

SomeClass foo()
{   
    ...
    return SomeClass();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are no leaks because the code is invalid and shouldn't even compile. You can't take the address of a temporary (`&foo()`).